# ADALJS Error description:AADSTS65001: No permission to access user information is configured for 'clientId' application, or it is expired or revoked

Tags: azure-active-directory, adal

I am trying to use ADALJS(https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-js) to access Azure Active Directory.  I am successfully able to perform the login however when I try to make a webapi call I get the following error

Error description:AADSTS65001: No permission to access user information is configured for 'clientid' application, or it is expired or revoked.

Answer (score 0):

You can follow this sample to verify your application configuration : https://github.com/AzureADSamples/SinglePageApp-WebAPI-AngularJS-DotNet

You may be missing to enable Oauth2 implicit flow in the manifest.